# ActiveRecord - getting query results for row N to row N+10

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I know this probably has been asked before (In fact, I'm pretty sure of it).

Suppose I have a model Article, and want to find all articles that fit a certain condition, ordered by date.

```
Article.find(:conditions => [SOME CONDITION], :order => "date asc")
```

if I want to get the 10th to 20th rows from this query, how do I do so with ActiveRecord?

I am using Postgres, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails 3 notation for this would be:

```
Article.where(...conditions...).order('date ASC').limit(10).offset(10)
```

What you probably want is a pagination tool like [Paginator](http://paginator.rubyforge.org) or something similar. It will provide an interface to show page N instead of having to do the limit and offset calculations yourself.

Comment: +1, this is usually about pagination.  See my answer if it's not.